# How to calculate the probability distribution of this random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

The random variable is defined by $$X=\left|g\right|^2\cdot d^{-\alpha}$$
where $\alpha>2$ is a positive real number, $g$ is complex Gaussian random variable with zero mean and unit variance and $d$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,d_{\mathrm{max}}]$. Also $g$ and $d$ are independent.

We can show that $|g|$ is Rayleigh distributed on $[0,\infty)$ and $|g|^2$ is exponentially distributed $[0,\infty)$.

The question becomes: What is the probability of $X=Y\cdot Z^{-\alpha}$ where $Y$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$ and $Z$ is uniformly distributed with parameters $a$ abd $b$ and both $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

---

Attempt:

From the [formula here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables) I could derive something.

$$\displaystyle
F_X(x)=\int_{0}^{d_{\mathrm{max}}}\dfrac{\lambda e^{-\lambda t}}{t}f_{Z^{-\alpha}}(x/t)dt
$$

Now I do not know what is the PDF of $Z^{-\alpha}$ when $Z$ is uniformly distributed.

It seems that the PDF of $X$ is complicated.

After some calculation, I found something like:

$$
F_X(x)=\dfrac{\lambda}{\alpha d_{\mathrm{max}}}\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{1/\alpha}\int_{0}^{xd_{\mathrm{max}}}e^{-\lambda t}t^{1/\alpha} dt
$$